# modify GCC ".md" machine definition template

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I'm now modifying the gcc's md file, for a mips(el) target. gcc src's version is 4.6.0.

I want to modify the sign-extend insn generation.

originally, mips use "`lb`"/"`lh`" instruction to sign-extend a byte/half.

but in my target CPU it doesn't has "`lb`" and "`lh`", it only support "`lbu`" and "`lhu`". so I have to generate such instructions to implement a sign-ext.

e.g.

> lb %0,%1

become:

> lbu %0,%1
>   srl %0,%0,24
>   sra %0,%0,24

similarly:

> lh %0,%1

become:

> lhu %0,%1
>   srl %0,%0,16
>   sra %0,%0,16

But, In original "md" file, two of these is a single pattern, it use macro to generate lb/lh instruction:

```
"l<SHORT:size>"

<SHORT:size> may be "b" or "h" --> "lb" or "lh"
```

but I want to get "24" from "b" ; get "16" form "h". How can I achieve this?

Comment: I fear there are quite few people who actually understand details of that format, but they are most likely to be reading gcc@gcc.gnu.org mailing list (or maybe [some other on gcc.gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html)), so I'd suggest you try asking there. It seems you should be able to post without subscribing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `lb` case what you want is to define three rules using a `define_insn` for `lbu`, `srl` and `sra` respectively. Once that is done you define an expansion rule using a `define_expand` for lb which expands into `lbu`, `srl` and `sra`.

At expansion time GCC will transform lb into `lbu`, `srl` and `sra`, meaning that during the RTL phase you won't have lb anymore but only things your backend will understand.

Similarly for `lh`.
The internal documents are not the best in the world unless you're already in-the-know, however they can be useful to you to look particular details when reading other peoples backends.

On `define_insn`: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Patterns.html#index-define_005finsn-3192
On `define_expand`: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Expander-Definitions.html#index-define_005fexpand-3613

Enjoy.

Comment: It been a long time since I post this question. I'm not playing with gcc now, but however I appreicate for your answer. I was just feel hard to modify the Lisp-like texts. Thanks!